# Zooming UIImageView in UITableViewCell with zoom

Tags: ios, uiimageview, scrollview, zooming

I have a following issue:
I got next tableviewcell architecture,

- UITableViewCell

  - containerView

    - scrollView (for zooming UIImageView)

      - UIImageView

The problem is that when I zoom in the UIImageView , it always bounces to the top-left point of the picture, at any zoom.And when I zoom out it is visible that zooms out to left top corner.

**No Constraints, Everything created programmatically**

Tried all techniques I could find on stack overflow but none solved it.I think the reason is that something wrong with doing it in uitableviewcell.That's what inside of my TableViewCell.swift

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenWidth)
    self.ImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,screenWidth,screenWidth)
    self.CameraView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,screenWidth,screenWidth)
    self.ScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,screenWidth,screenWidth)
    self.addSubview(CameraView)

    //!----Scroll view----//
    ScrollView.delegate = self
    ScrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
    ScrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
    ScrollView.bounces = false
    ScrollView.bouncesZoom = false
    ScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    ScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0
    ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(screenWidth, screenWidth)

    ScrollView.pagingEnabled = false

    var doubleTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "scrollViewDoubleTapped:")
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    ScrollView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapRecognizer)
    self.contentView.addSubview(ScrollView)
    self.ScrollView.addSubview(ImageView)

    var centerPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.ScrollView.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.ScrollView.bounds))
    ImageView.center = centerPoint
    ScrollView.center = centerPoint
    ImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    ImageView.clipsToBounds = false

    centerScrollViewContents()


}
func centerScrollViewContents(){
    var boundsSize:CGSize = self.ScrollView.bounds.size
    var contentsFrame = self.ImageView.frame

    if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width){
        contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width)/2
    }else{
        contentsFrame.origin.x = 0
    }

    if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height){
        contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height)/2
    }else{
        contentsFrame.origin.y = 0
    }

    self.ImageView.frame = contentsFrame
}
func scrollViewDoubleTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // 1
    let pointInView = recognizer.locationInView(ImageView)

    // 2
    var newZoomScale = ScrollView.zoomScale * 1.5
    newZoomScale = min(newZoomScale, ScrollView.maximumZoomScale)

    // 3
    let scrollViewSize = ScrollView.bounds.size
    let w = scrollViewSize.width / newZoomScale
    let h = scrollViewSize.height / newZoomScale
    let x = pointInView.x - (w / 2.0)
    let y = pointInView.y - (h / 2.0)

    let rectToZoomTo = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

    // 4
    ScrollView.zoomToRect(rectToZoomTo, animated: true)
}


func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    centerScrollViewContents()
}

func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return self.ImageView
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you have to use constraints for iOS8 to position items. I had this problem with my code working on iOS7 by setting frame positions etc and not working at all on iOS8. Have you tried it on iOS7 to see what happens? If it works there and not on iOS8, then you thats your issue. The solution is to add a left and top offset constraint for the image and set the constraint sizes in code followed by forcing a layout.

Comment: have you tried setting contentMode in the scrollView or the ImageView to `Center `?

Comment: tried ,none helped.
@RoryMcKinnel thank you for suggestion, I ll try this out today

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel can you please  explain it to me more elaborating since I quite dont get how to do that.

Comment: @GrishaGevorkyan I think I misread what your issue was. Looking again, your code all seems to come from the following tutorial and you are trying to spice it into a table cell: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift. Your best bet is to get the tutorial code working and then use that to debug your adjustments side by side to see what is different. I would strip your cell back to the minimum of just an image view and get that working.  You seem to add a CameraView to the cell view rather than its content view which might be an issue?

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel I found that the problem was caused by class SWTableViewCell and scrolling of 2 different Scroll Views just conflicted, sad but I ll have to sacrifice one for another.
Anyway thank you very much for your effort to help me , appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to your scenario is add a View(zoomView) inside ScrollView as the parent of UIImageView, and then without adding the gestures just return the zoomViev from the method     `func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?`.
And then to maintain the zoom level while reloading the tableView, store the zoomLevel of the ScrollView in the method    `func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` and use that stored zoomLevel it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method